# How to remove key based on condition in array object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to remove particular key in object array javascript.
In the array object `obj`, if the id is null remove the key in javascript

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  field: "finance"
}, {
  id: null,
  field: "service}, {
  id: 2,
  field: "information"
}]

functionremoveKey(arrobj) {
  return arrobj.filter(e => {
    if (e.id == null) {
      delete e.id;
    }
  }
}

var result = removeKey(obj);
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  { id: 1, field: "finance" },
  { field: "service" },
  { id: 2, field: "information" }
]
```

Comment: That's not what `.filter()` is meant to be used for/as. You either want `.forEach()` or `.map()`

Comment: You're missing a quote after `service`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Try this `obj.forEach(e => { if (e.id === null) { delete e.id } });`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `map` for this:

```js
var obj = [{ id: 1, field: "finance"}, { id: null, field: "service"}, { id: 2, field: "information"}]
result = obj.map(val=>val.id ? val : (delete val.id, val));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mutate the source, you can use the following:

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  field: "finance"
}, {
  id: null,
  field: "service"
}, {
  id: 2,
  field: "information"
}]

function removeKey(arrobj, keyname) {
  return arrobj.map(e => 
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(e).filter(
        ([k, v]) => v !== null || keyname !== k
      )
    )
  )
}

console.log(removeKey(obj, 'id'));
```

It makes use of the `Object.fromEntries` method, which is relatively new, if your environment doesn't support it, use this instead:

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  field: "finance"
}, {
  id: null,
  field: "service"
}, {
  id: 2,
  field: "information"
}]

function removeKey(arrobj, keyname) {
  return arrobj.map(e => 
    Object
      .entries(e)
      .filter(([k, v]) => v !== null || keyname !== k)
      .reduce((obj, [k, v]) => (obj[k] = v, obj), {})
  )
}

console.log(removeKey(obj, 'id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) mentions you'll want to iterate over the elements and remove the key rather than trying to filter the whole array. Something like the following would work:

```js
var arr = [
    { id: 1, field: "finance" },
    { id: null, field: "service" },
    { id: 2, field: "information" }
];

function removeKey(arr) {
    arr.forEach(element => {
        if (element.id == null) {
            delete element.id;
        }                
    });
}

removeKey(arr);
console.log(arr);
```